# swri-ros-pkg and MotoPlus IDE

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I downloaded the ROS stack Desktop-Full Install and it works well. Now, I want to create a DX100 Server Application (http://www.ros.org/wiki/dx100/Tutorials/Creating_DX100_Server_Application). I have the swri-ros-pkg-read-only repository in my laptop, but I suppose I must add it to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH system variable.

This is my setup.sh file:
#!/bin/sh
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
export ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/electric/ros
export PATH=$ROS_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export PYTHONPATH=$ROS_ROOT/core/roslib/src:$PYTHONPATH
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

I think I have to change the last line, but I'm not sure how it must be. Additionally, I haven't used MotoPlus IDE, so I would like to know where I can find some tutorials or information about it.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32163/swri-ros-pkg-and-motoplus-ide/) by [jcgarciaca](https://answers.ros.org/users/2187/jcgarciaca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2012-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you are asking two questions here:

#1. How to build a ROS package/stack - You are correct that your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH needs to be updated to include the location where you placed ROS-Industrial.  It should looks something like:

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=:~/ros_workspace:/opt/ros/electric/stacks:$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH.  Once this is set you should be able to run rosmake from the stack of interest.

#2. How to build the server application (which resides on the Motoman controller) - This requires MotoPlus and associated documentation.  This is available from Motoman.  This part should make more sense when you get familiar with MotoPlus.

FYI...It appears you are using ROS Electric.  Some parts of ROS-Industrial rely on Fuerte functionality.  I suggest you upgrade ( http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu )

---

Originally posted by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) with karma: 1601 on 2012-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0